# Почему использование % для перемещения буквы на определенное количество мест в массиве приводит к исчезновению массива?

Tags: c

Я хочу "зашифровать" (т.е. обратимо скрыть) строку, сдвинув каждую букву на определенное количество мест. Поэтому я попробовал 3:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    string code;
    int i;
    code = get_string("Write your plaintext...\n");
    for(i=0;i<strlen(code);i++)
    {
        if (code[i]!=' '&code[i]!='!'&code[i]!='?'&code[i]!='.')
        {
        code[i]= ((code[i]+3)%26);

        //printf("%i%c\n",i,code[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", code);

}
```

Но я ничего не получаю в ответ:

```
~/pset2/ $ ./caesar_hugues 
Write your plaintext...
Hello World!

~/pset2/ $
```

Поэтому, когда вы сделали только (code[i]+3), это работает, но не работает для букв в конце abcedar.

Пробовал добавлять, например, букву «а»:

```
printf("%c", ('a' + code[i]+3)%26);
```

Но ничего не возвращает

```
~/pset2/ $ ./caesar_hugues 
Write your plaintext...
Hello, World!
```

Comment: Это называется обфусцировать. Операция `%` является необратимой.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш комментарий, @user7860670 что это такое? А как еще мы можем это сделать?

Comment: Однако когда я просто печатаю printf("%c", (code[i]+3)%26);, он вообще ничего не возвращает, даже ошибку @user7860670

Comment: функция `printf` печатает строку **до** встречи буквы `'\00'` Она вам и попалась. попробуйте добавить, например букву `'a'`. `code[i]= 'a' + ((code[i]+3)%26);`

Comment: Хорошо, я только что сделал это, но ничего не возвращает: @AlexGlebe я добавил код

Answer (score 0):

`'e'` имеет ASCII код `101`. Добавим `3` возьмём по модулю `26`: `(101 + 3) % 26 = 104 % 26 = 0`. `'e'` вторая буква во фразе `"Hello, World!"`. То есть, на второй итерации вашего цикла в строку вписывается ноль, который обозначает конец ASCIIZ строки. Цикл прерывается, в заголовке `strlen(code)`, который теперь вернёт `1`.

[AlexGlebe](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/288358/alexglebe) предложил вам добавить `'a'` чтобы такого не было. У вас не получилось. Вот работающий код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char code[] = "Hello, World!";
    size_t i;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(code);i++)
    {
        if ((code[i]!=' ')&(code[i]!='!')&(code[i]!='?')&(code[i]!='.'))
        {
        code[i]= 'a' + ((code[i]+3)%26);
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", code);
}
```

> ```
> $ gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O cipher.c && ./a.out 
> xahhkv mknhz!
> ```

P.S. Этот код всё ещё ужасен. Нет, **УЖАСЕН!!!**. Но это предмет для других вопросов.